Manga where the main character has an ability that makes any girl who locks eyes with him fall in love with him
I remember seeing a manga where the main character is given an ability that makes any girl who locks eyes with him fall in love with him, and he somehow affects the whole school.
I can't remember the name. Any answers?

Do you recall how the MC gained this ability?

No I do not, I think it just kinda happened in the middle of a duel.

What kind of duel? And was this full colour or mostly black & white?

Could this be Rokudo's Bad Girls (Rokudō no Onna-tachi)?

Tousuke Rokudou is physically weak and cowardly attending a school
filled with delinquent students. He and his two friends live in
constant fear and is regularly bullied, leading to the trio venting
their frustrations in private in the school's restroom. Upon receiving
a scroll from his grandfather, Rokudou gains a special pentagram mark
on his forehead. Rokudou's ancestors used this spell to exorcise oni,
but in the modern day, the spell causes any "bad girl" to instantly
fall in love with him once he makes eye contact with them. His school
life drastically changes as not only is he thrust into the delinquent
culture of his school, but he encounters several girls, each one
presenting a new problem. He helps rehabilitate most of the girls
focused on, each one genuinely falling in love with Rokudou or
becoming a close ally.



No this wasn't it, I remember that it was a world with magic.

@Lucas - That's the sort of detail you should edit into your question.
